# Ratio of median to mean

Tags: distributions, descriptive-statistics, skewness, central-tendency

Is the ratio of the median to the mean of a distribution used for any descriptors e.g. measure of skewness?

Comment: Not without restrictions: such a ratio could have a meaning only for general distributions whose values are all positive or all negative or perhaps for distributions from some parametric family.  When it does have a meaning, it looks like your question becomes tautological: this property is whatever it is.  If you choose to call it a form of "skewness" you may, but that sheds no light on its interpretation.

Comment: BTW, you can explore the relationships between medians and means in other posts on this site: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=median+mean+skewness.

Answer (score 6):

Not that I know of, but there's a related concept: the [Nonparametric skew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_skew). Let $\mu$ be the mean $\sigma$ the standard deviation and $\nu$ the median. The Nonparametric skew is

$$S = \frac{\mu-\nu}{\sigma}$$

Yours is

$$S^* = \mu/\nu=(S \sigma + \nu)/\nu=S\sigma/\nu+1$$

And also

$$S = (S^*-1)/(\sigma/\nu)$$

Answer (score 3):

So glad you asked this question:

In my undergrad thesis I did an econometric hypothesis test and demonstrated a relationship between (lagged) income inequality and economic growth. I used the Gini index as a measure of income inequality -- conventional.

But my advisor was most impressed with an appendix I wrote where I demonstrated that the Gini index is non-linear and the ratio of median to mean might be a better candidate for use in linear regression models.

For a typical left-skewed distribution, the Gini might be around 0.45.  As we move toward a more normalized or equal distribution, the Gini index would drop. If, hypothetically, we kept moving toward a right-skewed distribution, the Gini index would again rise. Hence non-linear.

In contrast the ratio of median to mean would be linear; if we start with an extremely left-skewed distribution and move thru a normal distribution and continue toward a more right-skewed distribution, the ratio of median to mean continues to increase from Mm < 1.0 to Mm = 1.0 to Mm > 1.0.

As whuber points out above, the use of this descriptive stat is constrained to distributions whose values are always positive. So this is compelling as a descriptor of an income distribution. :D

Comment: And as you have, I called the ratio of median to mean "skewness". This was 1987. :)

Comment: Thank you for the answers and as a result, I'm stuck to pick a "winner". The first answer is "purer", the second has an interesting application

Comment: @DaveFer if you're still around, is more of your Gini analysis posted online? I don't quite follow and would like to know more, but this question isn't an appropriate place for that.

Comment: @Foobar Apologies, I just saw your info request. No my paper was done in 1987 (?) and exists only in the files of my Econometrics professor. But this is a simple concept that can be demo'd with a quick thought experiment. (Additionally, I'd be happy to discuss it with you by e-mail: davefer_work@hotmail.com).